# SQL Server foreign key constraints issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 tables :

1. dog
2. dogowner

I am trying to create a foreign key from DogOwner to Dog but not on the Primary Key of the dog table.
I am planning to create my own unique id's for the dog table's dog_id column. 
Herewith the schemas :

```
CREATE TABLE dog(
    id          INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),
    dog_id      INT NOT NULL,
    dog_name    VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    create_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    update_date DATETIME DEFAULT getutcdate(),
    start_date  DATETIME DEFAULT getutcdate(),
    end_date    DATETIME DEFAULT getDate() - 101,
    is_active   BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (id,dog_id)
    );

CREATE TABLE dogowner(
    dogowner_id  INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    dog_id       INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (dog_id) REFERENCES dog(dog_id)
    );
```

As soon as I create the foreign key constraint on the dogowner table it fails with the following error :

```
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dog' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__dogowner__dog_id__00AA174D'.
```

**> UPDATE :**

So eventually I dropped the complicated Schema design and opted for history tables on every table
that I want to version.So the dog table will have a dog_history or dog_log table with a post insert/update done on all the history tables.

This is not the way I wanted to do it but it allows me to have foreign key constraints in my database, soft deletes and logging of data. Thanks all for the input. I am following the KISS principle.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're trying to point `dog_id` from `dogowner` to a key in `dog`. The only key existing in `dog` is the primary combo key on `id, dog_id`. Thus, it cannot match `dog_id` to any keys in the `dog` table.

Comment: Why would you need/want to add your own id column, by the way?

Comment: Hi @SchmitzIT this is for versioning purposes on the table. I plan to keep the history of the record when any updates/deletes are done. I can easily do something like this in mySQL. I would like to use the dog_id as my foreign key in the dogowner table.
So for soft deletes on the dog table, the record will be marked as inactive ( is_active = 0 ) and for updates, a new record will be inserted on the dog table but the dog_id will stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dog_id field needs to be unique field, the following will work:

```
create table dog(
id int not null identity(1,1),
dog_id int unique not null,
dog_name varchar(200) not null,
create_date datetime not null ,
update_date datetime default getutcdate(),
start_date datetime default getutcdate(),
end_date datetime default getDate() - 101,
is_active bit not null default '0',
primary key(id,dog_id)
);

create table dogowner(
dogowner_id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
dog_id int not null,
foreign key(dog_id) references dog(dog_id)
);
```

From the MSFT [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> You can use UNIQUE constraints to make sure that no duplicate values
>   are entered in specific columns that do not participate in a primary
>   key. Although both a UNIQUE constraint and a PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   enforce uniqueness, use a UNIQUE constraint instead of a PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint when you want to enforce the uniqueness of a column, or
>   combination of columns, that is not the primary key.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi @Milica, the unique key wont work for my purposes. I want to maintain version history on the dog table. The same dog_id will be inserted multiple times on the dog table. eg.
insert into dog(dog_id,dog_name,create_date) values(1,'joe',GETUTCDATE());
insert into dog(dog_id,dog_name,create_date) values(1,'max',GETUTCDATE());

The insert statements imply that the dog withthe name 'Joe' was changed to 'Max'.

Comment: But then you cannot reference dog_id with a foreign key because the column that is referenced has to be unique.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I have updated my question with the solution I settled on for versioning my database. Your answer did solve the question regarding the error I received from SQL Server, therefore I am marking it as SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

First create unique key on dog_id field in dog table and create unique constraint on it and then you can refer this unique key as foreign key in Dog_owner table.